Form is freezzing when using datagridview with validation
I've created a form where you can enter data via DataGridView. The DataGridView has RowValidating event assigned to the following function:
private void OnBindingRowValidate(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = bindingGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    if (row == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    DiagramElement element = row.Cells[0].Value as DiagramElement;
    int? anchorPointId = row.Cells[1].Value as int?;
    int? maxAnchorPointId = element?.MaxAnchorPointId;
    if (!maxAnchorPointId.HasValue) maxAnchorPointId = 0;
    if (!anchorPointId.HasValue || element == null) { e.Cancel = true; return; }
    if (anchorPointId.Value < 0 || anchorPointId.Value > maxAnchorPointId)
    { e.Cancel = true; }
}

For some reason the form hangs when DataGridView goes out of focus.
T debug the problem, I set breakpoint to the function described above. When DataGridView went out of focus, function executed normally, but form didn't react. When I repeated action that caused DataGridView to go out of focus, function executed again etc.
